# Django urls.py passing wrong GET value

Tags: python, django, url, get

I have a url in my app

```
path('owner/season/<season_name>', LV.owner_season, name='league-owner-season')
```

where I want to load a page based on the season that is passed.  The url in my browser is "mywebsite.com/owner/season/fall2018".  My views file looks like

```
def owner_season(request, season_name):
  data = check_if_owner(request)
  print(str(request))
  if not data['valid_owner']:
    redirect('home')
  print(season_name)
  #other code doing classic django stuff
```

What gets printed is:

```
<WSGIRequest: GET '/owner/season/favicon.ico'>
favicon.ico
```

What would be causing the value of the GET value to change from urls to views?  From what I have read the value should be fall2018 but I have no idea where favicon.ico is coming from.

Comment: Solved,   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"> was causing the issue in html

Comment: FYI, the `fall2018` in the URL is not GET data. GET data is what is passed, usually from HTML forms, via a query string at the end of the URL. `fall2018` is a URL parameter